# Can we rename [mst3k] to [mystery-science-theater-3000]?

Tags: support, tags

Now that we can have more than 25 characters in tags, I'd like to recommend renaming [mst3k](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mst3k) to [mystery-science-theater-3000](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mystery-science-theater-3000), preserving the old one as a synonym. This site seems to prefer full names instead of abbreviations, so that would be consistent with other shows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your request has been fulfilled and the tag has been renamed and synonymized. Thank you for bringing this to notice.